# How to get the current tab value in swipe tabs using Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

We are working on Codename One "Swipe Tabs", we need the current tab index value but the method getSelectedIndex() giving us the previous tab index value on swipe, how can I get the current tab index?

Comment: I'm assuming you used a tabs selection listener. Notice that the arguments to that callback include two integers the offset of the old and new tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getSelectedIndex()

Returns the currently selected index for this tabbedpane. Returns -1 if there is no currently selected tab.

Returns:
    the index of the selected tab
```

getSelectedIndex() return the current tab index in which index of first tab is 0 and index of second tab is 1 and so on.
Please post your code (if possible)